# Logback Reciever - Can't handle model of type class ReceiverModel

Tags: java, sockets, logback

I cant get **Logback ServerSocketReceiver** to work. I get the exact same problem running Logback's own complete example https://logback.qos.ch/manual/receivers.html.

Simplified `logback.xml`:

```xml
<configuration debug="true">
    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>[%date]-%msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <root level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
    </root>
    <receiver class="ch.qos.logback.classic.net.server.ServerSocketReceiver">
        <port>3331</port>
    </receiver>
</configuration>
```

The socket server never even starts:

```java
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.DefaultProcessor@76b10754 - Can't handle model of type class ch.qos.logback.classic.model.ReceiverModel  with tag: receiver at line 11
```

Complete output with this setup:

```
20:22:22,951 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - This is logback-classic version 1.4.11
20:22:22,953 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer@305fd85d - No custom configurators were discovered as a service.
20:22:22,953 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer@305fd85d - Trying to configure with ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.SerializedModelConfigurator
20:22:22,953 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer@305fd85d - Constructed configurator of type class ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.SerializedModelConfigurator
20:22:22,971 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback-test.scmo]
20:22:22,971 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback.scmo]
20:22:22,978 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer@305fd85d - ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.SerializedModelConfigurator.configure() call lasted 19 milliseconds. ExecutionStatus=INVOKE_NEXT_IF_ANY
20:22:22,978 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer@305fd85d - Trying to configure with ch.qos.logback.classic.util.DefaultJoranConfigurator
20:22:22,978 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer@305fd85d - Constructed configurator of type class ch.qos.logback.classic.util.DefaultJoranConfigurator
20:22:22,979 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback-test.xml]
20:22:22,981 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Found resource [logback.xml] at [file:/home/x/Projects/agent-tcp-logging/server/target/classes/logback.xml]
20:22:23,067 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.AppenderModelHandler - Processing appender named [CONSOLE]
20:22:23,067 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.AppenderModelHandler - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender]
20:22:23,071 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.ImplicitModelHandler - Assuming default type [ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder] for [encoder] property
20:22:23,080 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.model.processor.RootLoggerModelHandler - Setting level of ROOT logger to DEBUG
20:22:23,081 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.AppenderRefModelHandler - Attaching appender named [CONSOLE] to Logger[ROOT]
20:22:23,084 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.DefaultProcessor@76b10754 - Can't handle model of type class ch.qos.logback.classic.model.ReceiverModel  with tag: receiver at line 11
20:22:23,085 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.ImplicitModelHandler - Ignoring unknown property [port] in [ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext]
20:22:23,085 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.DefaultProcessor@76b10754 - Can't handle model of type class ch.qos.logback.classic.model.ReceiverModel  with tag: receiver at line 11
20:22:23,085 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.DefaultProcessor@76b10754 - End of configuration.
20:22:23,086 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.JoranConfigurator@71a794e5 - Registering current configuration as safe fallback point
20:22:23,086 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer@305fd85d - ch.qos.logback.classic.util.DefaultJoranConfigurator.configure() call lasted 108 milliseconds. ExecutionStatus=DO_NOT_INVOKE_NEXT_IF_ANY
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

I tried Java 8, 11 and 17. I tried multiple versions of Logback, but would prefer  1.3.x, since I am stuck with Java 8 in production.(Eventually I would switch to SSLSocketReceiver/appender)

(The appender-side of Logback socket appender/reciever seems to work just fine. I connect a test SocketAppender to a small socket server using nc (https://linux.die.net/man/1/nc))

When Logback initializes I get
`ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.DefaultProcessor@76b10754 - Can't handle model of type class ch.qos.logback.classic.model.ReceiverModel  with tag: receiver at line 11`

I expect Logback to start a socket server to be started listening on port 3331.

Comment: What do you mean by this statement? `The appender seem to work. I made a 'fake' server which it connects to with no problem.`

Comment: Not important. Just that I tried make a program using the SocketAppender which seem to work. It connects to a fake server I make listening to the port. *Not* using Logback receiver... Just indicate that I seem to configure the apender side correctly, but not the receiver... Make sense?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using logback 1.3 then you need to pay attention to the Canonical (1.3) tab of the code example on the [page you linked](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/receivers.html#usingServerSocketReceiver):

[image: example]

---

##### Solution

```xml
<receiver class="ServerSocketReceiver">
    <port>3331</port>
</receiver>
```

The receiver xml must look like the above.

Note: class is `ServerSocketReceiver` not `ch.qos.logback.classic.net.server.ServerSocketReceiver`.

Comment: I tries multiple versions of logback, including 1.4 with same result.

Having said that, I tried the canonical again with logback 1.3.11. to be 100% sure. I get the exactly same result.

I also checkout source code with examples from github(tried 1.3.x and 1.4.x). It all gives me the same result:
"Can't handle model of type class ch.qos.logback.classic.model.ReceiverModel  with tag: receiver at line 17"

Comment: you put this in your xml? <receiver class="ServerSocketReceiver">
    <port>3331</port>
</receiver>

Comment: <configuration debug="true">
    <import class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder"/>
    <import class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender"/>
    <import class="ch.qos.logback.classic.net.server.ServerSocketReceiver"/>
    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder class="PatternLayoutEncoder">
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <root level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
    </root>
    <receiver class="ServerSocketReceiver">
        <port>3331</port>
    </receiver>
</configuration>

Comment: my previous comment was long answer meaning *yes* :-)

Comment: Yes your error is strange. I can't reproduce it.

Comment: CausingUnderflowsEverywhere thanks for trying.
So it works for you?

Comment: no, I didnt see it open a port, but no error message either. but my regular logging was working. Ill have to try with a new project later on.